# Troubles with finding/replacing in string

Tags: c#, string, replace, find

I am having some troubles finding/replacing a value in a string. Don´t know if i should do it in RegEx or C# has some nifty feature to make it work. Regex gives me headace.

The problem:

```
<doc name="tester" value="p1,p2,p3" />
```

So i want the "value" (p1,p2,p3) and replace it with the current value + ",p4".

Any help appriciated.

Comment: This looks like XML or potentially HTML, you should use a library for parsing those values (either the built in XML tools to .NET Framework or for HTML use HtmlAgilityPack)

Comment: could you show the start line and the final line you want please, i dont understand your explanations

Comment: You mention Regex "gives me headache". What have you tried so far?

Comment: you are not clear on your requirements: you want to add 'p4' only for 'doc' tags with the `name="tester"`, or every attribute `value="p1,p2,p3"` ?
if there was a `<doc name="tester" value="p1,p2,p3,p4,p5" />` should it turn into  `<doc name="tester" value="p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6" />` ?

Comment: @maccettura. Looks like it...but it´s not.

Comment: @Frenchy . I need to fetch the value...in this case it´s "p1,p2,p3"...then take that data put it so the line will be:
<doc name="tester" value="p1,p2,p3,p4" />

Comment: @JuanR Plenty, so much i have a headace.

Comment: @TomerW yes, you are correct...i want to edit the "value" content so it´s not p1,p2,p3...it should be oldcontent (p1,p2,p3)+newcontent(p4).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you get Regex headache, this is actually very simple to do with the following regex:

```
@"(?<=value=\"")[^""]+"
```

It starts by looking back for '`value="`', then it matches all character up to the ending double `quote`.

```
string test = @"<doc name=""tester"" value=""p1,p2,p3"" />";
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(?<=value=\"")[^""]+");
string result = regex.Replace(test, "p1,p2,p3,p4");

// result will be: @"<doc name=""tester"" value=""p1,p2,p3,p4"" />";
```

**Edit**:
You can of course capture the original content, simply by calling:

```
string match = regex.Match(test).Value;
```

Comment: Looks, pretty good. But can i "capture" what is in the actual value? I do not now beforehand what is in the actual value...just that´s a value that i must fetch and then add ",p4".

Comment: Thank you. For some reason i couldn´t cast match to a string...but used Match.Value...and it works very good!
Then in RegEx.replace i used concatenated Match.Value + ",p4".

Comment: Sorry typo, has been fixed.